# Get_Slug_Field() example for multiple slugs in Django 2.1?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-2.1

I want to find a way to add multiple slugs **from different models** to one view.

Either with get_slug_field and get_object; or other ways are appreciated as well..

But please, take into consideration that this is Generic View in which I am looking for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If your generic view is of type `View`, then you could declare it with the [ContextMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#contextmixin) and then `def get_context_data(**kwargs)` on the view.  If your view is a `TemplateView`, `ListView`, `DetailView`, etc., then you can do `def get_context_data(**kwargs)` without having to use a mixin.

Example using plain `View` and `ContextMixin` (you would need to do proper importing where necessary):

models.py:

```
class ModelOne(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(default='', max_length=75)


class ModelTwo(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(default='', max_length=75)
```

Note:  max_length defaults to 50; the 75 is arbitrary

views.py

```
class MyView(View, ContextMixin):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['slug_from_model_one'] = ModelOne.objects.get(...define your lookup...).slug
        context['slug_from_model_two'] = ModelTwo.objects.get(...define your lookup...).slug
        return context
```

Comment: Dear @Dan Swain, could you please show an example of code. I am trying to add two slugs into one Generic Detail View. I hope get_slug_field will help but I don't know how to write the code because I am a beginner.

Comment: Error: AttributeError at /study/corporate-finance/
Generic detail view SubjectDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.

I'm sure that I don't have a problem in my urlconf.

Comment: Because I have to add two different slugs, I have named them as subjectslug and studylevel slug.

Comment: Please post your url

Comment: path('study/<slug:subjectslug>/', views.SubjectDetailView.as_view(), name='subject-detail'),

Comment: In my URL I have only added one Slug for now, just to be sure that code works. Then I will add second Slug

Comment: Is subjectslug the name of the field on your model?  It would help if you would post your models.py and views.py file.  Looks like you're close.

Comment: You can see all my files including models.py and views.py in this link: https://github.com/ulvidamirli/my-django-project/tree/master/mynextstudy/mynextstudy/mnsdirectory

Comment: could you please write some updates about this problem. it is not solved yet. Thank you for your attention in advance.